# IS operator and where an object is coming from

Tags: c#

I have the following class written by someone else that I'm trying to understand (I omitted the code that is not necessary for this example):

```
public abstract class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
       ...

        public virtual bool IsAadmin(TheUser theUser)
        {
            if (Page is Page)
                return ((Page)Page).IsAadmin(theUser);

            return false;
        }
...
```

*Edit: (note: in stackoverflow the first `Page` in the `if` statement is highlighted blue but in visual studio it isn't)*

In the `if` statement intellisense shows that the first Page is of type `System.Web.UI.Page Control.Page` and the second `Page` is from `Something.Products.Web.Page`. When I debug through the code, it doesn't seem to go into this `if` statement, so I'm wondering what this code is trying to do? But more importantly where is that first `Page` in the `if` statement is coming from (initialized)? I'm using `Resharper` and it suggest replacing the `if` statement with

```
var page = Page as Page;
if (page != null)
```

This change shows that page is null when debugging through it.

Comment: Does `Page` show up as a member of the `UserControl` class or its parent, perhaps in the section of the code you removed from the post?

Comment: No, it has no mention of it in the UserControl class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "first page" is actually a `Page` property of `UserControl` class your abstract `UserControl` inherits from. It's of type `System.Web.UI.Page` and, as per documentation, returns

> a reference to the Page instance that contains the server control.

The `is` keyword evaluates to true when

> the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

It seems that when you were debugging your code, the examined `UserControl` was not contained in a page of type `Something.Products.Web.Page`.

Regarding the Resharper suggestion: in your original code, you are effectively casting the `Page` property twice - first, when using `is` keyword and second when casting it explicitly. With the code generated by Resharper, the cast only occurs once. When the `if` statement evaluates to true, you can be sure that the `page` variable holds a reference to the `Something.Products.Web.Page` and do not have to cast it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does explain a lot but confusing bit is Something.Products.Web.Page actually does inherit from System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: @astroboy I've edited my answer to make a bit about the `is` keyword more clear - hope that it makes more sense now.